# Capturing errors when Lambda bound to SQS queue

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Is there any way to capture Lambda errors in the above situation ?

Messages passed to a Lambda destination contain the error trace, but messages passed to a dead letter queue appear not to (just the request)

Because SQS is bound to Lambda (via `AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping`), the execution on the Lambda qualifies as synchronous, not asynchronous

In the synchronous case, the Lambda destination (if configured via `AWS::Lambda::EventConfig`) is ignored

Although `AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping` supports `DestinationConfig`, this is not supported when the source is SQS

The only way I can appear to handle an error message in such a case is via the SQS `RedrivePolicy` field - but this configures a dead letter queue, not a destination (ie no error trace)

Is there any way to capture the error trace in such a situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture lambda errors in your scenario using [CloudWatch subscriptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html).

CloudWatch will raise an event to Lambda or Kinesis if it receives a log entry matching a log group (e.g. function name) and text filter.

You job is to set up the subscription in CloudWatch and log errors in your lambda.